# Physical Review Letters Vs. Physics Letters

Tags: journals, physics

I know that The Physical Review A/B/E/X etc. are published by the APS and that Physical Letters A/B are by Elsavier, but which is better? Is there a substancial distinction between them?

Amir

Comment: Define 'better'.

Answer (score 1):

One difference is in their impact factors. Web of Science indicates that Physical Review Letters has an impact factor of 8.46, while Physics Letters A is 1.77 and Physics Letters B is 4.80.

However, the relevant question is which one publishes work in your particular area? Which do you and your colleagues read? If your sub-field does not read one or the other, then publishing there is not very productive.